# How to autopopulate the name and email filds from a page to another?

Tags: javascript, html

I have this scenario. People enter their name and email on a first page and how I can take that data and autofill on the next page?
Is possible this via url parameters?
Is so, How?

Comment: It's possible. If you want to use the URL parameter, check on the page load, and if exists, do something.

Answer (score 0):

You can send the parameters through the URL to the other page...

For example, your URL when you call the other page can be of the following format:

[www.myurl.com?name=JANE&email=jane@hotmal.com](http://www.myurl.com?name=JANE&email=jane@hotmal.com)

In the other page, make sure you check to see if there are any parameters included in the URL, and do the corresponding action.

Reference: https://easyautotagging.com/javascript-get-url-parameter/